# How do I go about solving this ownership problem?

Tags: rust, ownership

So I have this code right here ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4cdc318db136b2cd5e381b32039845d4)):

```rs
use std::error::Error;

struct Foo {
    data: Vec<i32>,
    counter: i32
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(counter: i32) -> Self {
        Self { data: vec![1, 2, 3], counter }
    }

    fn some_method(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        for num in self.data.iter() {
            println!("{num}");
            self.some_mut_recursive_method()?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    /// A useless recursive method that takes in a number, decrements it, checks if its greater than 0. If so it then 
    /// pushes the number onto the list of numbers and call it on the decremented number.
    fn some_mut_recursive_method(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        self.counter -= 1;

        if self.counter > 0 {
            self.data.push(self.counter);
            self.some_mut_recursive_method()?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new(10);

    foo.some_method();
}
```

It's a struct `Foo` that has a method that iterates over some internal data and calls a mutable recursive function that manipulates the internal state and possibly calls itself again. Now the problem is on line 16. You see, `self` is already borrowed immutably in `self.data.iter()`. But it has to call a mutable function on line 16, but it can't! I get an error saying

```
cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Again, it's borrowed as immutable in `self.data.iter()`. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f95d2dfc84b042ebaf672f26ad898b67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change self while iterating over its attribute.

One way to fix it is to use interior mutability (be careful this is not thread safe example). This might lead to very strange results as you are changing it during iteration:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::error::Error;

struct Foo {
    data: RefCell<Vec<i32>>,
    counter: RefCell<i32>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(counter: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: RefCell::new(vec![1, 2, 3]), counter: RefCell::new(counter)
        }
    }

    fn some_method(& self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        for num in self.data.borrow().iter() {
            println!("{num}");
            self.some_mut_recursive_method()?;
        }


        Ok(())
    }

    /// A useless recursive method that takes in a number, decrements it, checks if its greater than 0. If so it then
    /// pushes the number onto the list of numbers and call it on the decremented number.
    fn some_mut_recursive_method(& self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut counter = self.counter.borrow_mut();
        *counter -= 1;

        // if counter is greater than 0, push it onto the list of numbers and call this method again
        if *counter > 0 {
            self.data.borrow_mut().push(*counter);
            self.some_mut_recursive_method()?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new(10);

    foo.some_method();
}
```

another working method is to clone the whole vector into iterator:

```
use std::error::Error;

struct Foo {
    data: Vec<i32>,
    counter: i32
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(counter: i32) -> Self {
        Self { data: vec![1, 2, 3], counter }
    }

    fn some_method(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        for num in self.data.clone().iter() {
            println!("{num}");
            self.some_mut_recursive_method()?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    /// A useless recursive method that takes in a number, decrements it, checks if its greater than 0. If so it then
    /// pushes the number onto the list of numbers and call it on the decremented number.
    fn some_mut_recursive_method(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        self.counter -= 1;

        if self.counter > 0 {
            self.data.push(self.counter);
            self.some_mut_recursive_method()?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new(10);

    foo.some_method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this prob would be

```
use std::error::Error;

struct Foo {
    data: Vec<i32>,
    counter: i32
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(counter: i32) -> Self {
        Self { data: vec![1, 2, 3], counter }
    }

    fn some_method(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut result = vec![];
        for num in self.data.iter() {
            println!("{num}");
            let mut counter = self.counter;
            self.some_mut_recursive_method(&mut result, counter)?;
        }
        
        println!("{:?}", result);

        Ok(())
    }

    /// A useless recursive method that takes in a number, decrements it, checks if its greater than 0. If so it then 
    /// pushes the number onto the list of numbers and call it on the decremented number.
    fn some_mut_recursive_method(&self, res: &mut Vec<i32>, mut counter: i32) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        counter -= 1;

        if counter > 0 {
            res.push(counter);
            self.some_mut_recursive_method(res, counter)?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new(10);

    foo.some_method();
}
```